# Windows 8 Store App Call with Initial Argument Parameters

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, onload-event

On launch of my Win8 Store App I want to pass argument parameters.

I was looking at the following method that is called in the App class.  Looks like it is passing arguments along, so my question is how do I pass arguments to "`OnLaunched`" ? Essentially when I run the app straight away from the Win8 Menu

```
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These arguments can be passed in via a secondary tile that could be used to launch the app to a specified page during application launch.

I typically use a ViewManager to manage the view to be displayed based on these arguments.

App.cs

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[Constants.APP_PARAMETERS] = args.Arguments;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when already running, just ensure that
    // the window is active
    if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
    {
        Window.Current.Activate();

        await ViewManager.Instance.LaunchView();

        return;
    }
```

ViewManager:

```
public class ViewManager
{
    #region Singleton
    private ViewManager()
    {
    }

    static ViewManager _viewManager = null;

    public static ViewManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_viewManager == null)
            {
                _viewManager = new ViewManager();
            }

            return _viewManager;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public async Task LaunchView()
    {
        bool displaySubheader = false;
        var displayBackbutton = false;

        var arguments = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[Constants.APP_PARAMETERS] as string;
        var argumentsExist = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(arguments);

        if (!argumentsExist)
        {
            await UIServices.Instance.Load(typeof(HomePage), null, displaySubheader, displayBackbutton);
        }
        else
        {
            displaySubheader = true;
            displayBackbutton = false;
            await UIServices.Instance.Load(typeof(GroupPage), arguments, displaySubheader, displayBackbutton);

            var groupId = new Guid(arguments);

            await ReadPost(groupId);
        }
    }
```